# Drawn coin gambling game probability and deviation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have been thinking about this probability problem for hours but could not solve it. Can anyone give me some help?
Here is the problem:

> Coins with values 1 through N (inclusive) are placed into a bag. All the coins from the bag are iteratively drawn (without replacement) at random. For the first coin, you are paid the value of the coin. For subsequent coins, you are paid the absolute difference between the drawn coin and the previously drawn coin. For example, if you drew 5,3,2,4,1. Your payments would be 5,2,1,2,3 for a total payment of 13.
>
> Questions:
>   1) What is the standard deviation of your total payment for N=20?
>   2) What is the probability that your total payment is greater than or equal to 160 for N=20?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Hint: Everything hinges on the value of the first coin drawn.

Comment: Do we have to draw all the 20 coins?

Comment: Graham, I tried to obtain deviation by brute force but it only works for small N. Besides, I also find that the expectation of the payment can be obtained form a N*N matrix, where the element (i,j) is the abs(i-j) for i!=j. But for i==j. element is i. Sum up all the elements and divide the sum by N is the mean.

Comment: Lakshya, yes, we have to draw all the 20 coins.

Comment: @LoveCoding9000 The expected value can be compressed to closed-form $(n+1)(2n+1)/6$. Also: Note that $\sigma = \sqrt{E[X^2] - (E[X])^2}$

Comment: I know the mean of the first chosen item is (n+1)/2 and backtracking, I can see that the mean of the sum of the remaining items must be (n^2 - 1)/3 but how do you arrive at that?

Answer (score 3):

The question originally asked for a calculation of the standard deviation. The first answer showed how to calculate the expected value and suggested to use a similar procedure to evaluate the standard deviation. Since a calculation of the standard deviation has again been requested now, here it is:

We have (with the notation from Graham Kemp’s answer) $S=X_1+\sum_{k=2}^N|X_k-X_{k-1}|$ and thus

\begin{eqnarray}
\def\e{\mathsf E}
\e(S)
&=&
\e\left(X_1+\sum_{k=2}^N|X_k-X_{k-1}|\right)
\\
&=&
\e\left(X_1\right)+\sum_{k=2}^N\e\left(|X_k-X_{k-1}|\right)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

The expected value of the first coin is just $\frac12(N+1)$. There are $N-j$ pairs at distance $j$ from each other, with $1\le j\le N-1$, and all pairs are equally likely, so

\begin{eqnarray}
\e\left(|X_k-X_{k-1}|\right)
&=&
\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}(N-j)j}{\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}(N-j)}
\\
&=&
\frac{\frac16(N-1)N(N+1)}{\frac12(N-1)N}
\\
&=&
\frac13(N+1)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Thus, in total

\begin{eqnarray}
\e(S)
&=&
\frac12(N+1)+(N-1)\cdot\frac13(N+1)
\\
&=&
\frac16(N+1)(2N+1)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

The expected value of the square of $S$ is

\begin{eqnarray}
\e\left(S^2\right)
&=&
\e\left(\left(X_1+\sum_{k=2}^N|X_k-X_{k-1}|\right)^2\right)
\\
&=&
\e\left(X_1^2\right)+2\sum_{k=2}^N\e\left(X_1\cdot|X_k-X_{k-1}|\right)+\e\left(\left(\sum_{k=2}^N|X_k-X_{k-1}|\right)^2\right)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Let’s go through the terms one by one. The first one is

\begin{eqnarray}
\e\left(X_1^2\right)
&=&
\frac1N\sum_{k=1}^Nk^2
\\
&=&
\frac16(N+1)(2N+1)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Interestingly, the expectation of the square of the first term is the expectation of the entire sum. Perhaps this indicates that we could have obtained $\e(S)$ more easily, but I don’t immediately see how. Anyway, the second term is easier to evaluate if we at first ignore the restriction that $X_1\ne X_k$ for $k\ne1$. Then

$$
\sum_{x_1=1}^N\sum_{x_{k-1}\lt x_k}x_1(x_k-x_{k-1})=\frac{N(N+1)}2\cdot\frac{(N-1)N(N+1)}6\;,
$$

and this accounts for $\frac{N^2(N-1)}2$ triples; from this we have to subtract a contribution where $X_1=X_{k-1}\lt X_k$:

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{x_1=1}^N\sum_{x_k=x_1+1}^Nx_1(x_k-x_1)
&=&
\sum_{x_1=1}^Nx_1(N-x_1)\left(\frac{x_1+1+N}2-x_1\right)
\\
&=&
\frac{(N-1)N(N+1)(N+2)}{24}
\end{eqnarray}

and a contribution where $X_{k-1}\lt X_k=X_1$:

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{x_1=1}^N\sum_{x_{k-1}=1}^{x_1-1}x_1(x_1-x_{k-1})
&=&
\sum_{x_1=1}^Nx_1(x_1-1)\left(x_1-\frac{x_1}2\right)
\\
&=&
\frac{(N-1)N(N+1)(3N+2)}{24}\;,
\end{eqnarray}

which together account for $N(N-1)$ triples. Thus we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\e\left(X_1\cdot|X_2-X_1|\right)
&=&\frac{(N-1)N(N+1)((N+2)+(3N+2))}{24N(N-1)}
\\
&=&
\frac16(N+1)^2
\end{eqnarray}

and

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=3}^N\e\left(X_1\cdot|X_k-X_{k-1}|\right)
&=&
(N-2)\frac{\frac1{12}(N-1)N^2(N+1)^2-\frac16(N-1)N(N+1)^2}{\frac12N^2(N-1)-N(N-1)}
\\
&=&
\frac16(N-2)(N+1)^2\;,
\end{eqnarray}

for a total of

$$
\sum_{k=2}^N\e\left(X_1\cdot|X_k-X_{k-1}|\right)=\frac16(N-1)(N+1)^2\;.
$$

Interestingly, the contributions for $k=2$ and $k\gt2$ are the same, which again suggests that we could have derived them more easily, but again I don’t immediately see how.

For the last term, we get three different terms upon multiplying it out. The first is just a sum of squares where we don’t need absolute values, so this is easily computed (recall that there are $N-j$ pairs at distance $j$ from each other):

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=2}^N\e\left(\left(X_k-X_{k-1}\right)^2\right)
&=&
(N-1)\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}(N-j)j^2}{\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}(N-j)}
\\
&=&
(N-1)\frac{\frac1{12}(N-1)N^2(N+1)}{\frac12(N-1)N}
\\
&=&
\frac16(N-1)N(N+1)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

The second one is over the products $|X_k-X_{k-1}|\cdot|X_{k+1}-X_k|$. We can evaluate it by summing over all ordered triples with nearest-neighbour distances $i$ and $j$, of which there are $N-i-j$. There are three equiprobable cases: The distances being multiplied can be $i$ and $j$, $i$ and $i+j$ or $j$ and $i+j$, so we have to sum over $\frac13(ij+i(i+j)+j(i+j))=\frac13(i^2+j^2+3ij)$:

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=2}^{N-1}\e\left(|X_k-X_{k-1}|\cdot|X_{k+1}-X_k|\right)
&=&
(N-2)\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N-2}\sum_{j=1}^{N-1-i}\frac13(i^2+j^2+3ij)(N-i-j)}{\sum_{i=1}^{N-2}\sum_{j=1}^{N-1-i}(N-i-j)}
\\
&=&
(N-2)\frac{\frac1{360}(N-2)(N-1)N(N+1)(7N+4)}{\frac16(N-2)(N-1)N}
\\
&=&
\frac1{60}(N-2)(N+1)(7N+4)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

The third one is over independent products. Here we can sum over all ordered quadruples with nearest-neighbour distances $i$, $j$ and $k$, of which there are $N-i-j-k$. There are again three equiprobable cases: The distances being multiplied can be $i$ and $k$, $i+j$ and $j+k$, or $i+j+k$ and $j$, so we have to sum over $\frac13(ik+(i+j)(j+k)+(i+j+k)j)$:

\begin{eqnarray}
\e\left(|X_4-X_3|\cdot|X_2-X_1|\right)
&=&
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N-3}\sum_{j=1}^{N-2-i}\sum_{k=1}^{N-1-i-j}\frac13(ik+(i+j)(j+k)+(i+j+k)j)(N-i-j-k)}{\sum_{i=1}^{N-3}\sum_{j=1}^{N-2-i}\sum_{k=1}^{N-1-i-j}(N-i-j-k)}
\\
&=&
\frac{\frac1{1080}(N-3)(N-2)(N-1)N(N+1)(5N+4)}{\frac1{24}(N-3)(N-2)(N-1)N}
\\
&=&
\frac1{45}(N+1)(5N+4)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Of these terms we have $(N-3)(N-2)$, since we can choose one of $N-3$ positions for one neighbouring pair among $N-4+2$ objects (two pairs and the remaining $N-4$ coins) and then one $N-2$ for the other.

Putting it all together, keeping in mind the factors of $2$ omitted in between, we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\e\left(S^2\right)
&=&
\frac16(N+1)(2N+1)+\frac13(N-1)(N+1)^2+\frac16(N-1)N(N+1)
\\
&&
+\frac1{30}(N-2)(N+1)(7N+4)+\frac1{45}(N-3)(N-2)(N+1)(5N+4)
\\
&=&
\frac1{90}(N+1)(10N^3+24N^2+5N+9)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Thus, the variance of the sum is

\begin{eqnarray}
\e\left(S^2\right)-\e(S)^2
&=&
\frac1{90}(N+1)(10N^3+24N^2+5N+9)-\left(\frac16(N+1)(2N+1)\right)^2
\\
&=&
\frac1{180}(N+1)\left(8N^2-15N+13\right)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

[Here’s Java code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/cb57cb87436a648cea5566e2792c3d58) that verifies the result.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\lvert{#1}\right\rvert}$Let $X_k$ be the value of the $k$-th coin drawn.

Then $S = X_1 +\sum_{k=2}^N \abs{X_k-X_{k-1}}$ is the payment.

Thus $\mathsf E(S)=\mathsf E(X_1)+\sum_{k=2}^N\mathsf E(\abs{X_k-X_{k-1}})$ due to the Linearity of Expectation.

Now $\mathsf E(X_1)= \dfrac{N+1}{2}$

And for every $k\in \{2..N\}$, $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(\abs{ X_k-X_{k-1} }) ~&=~ \mathsf E(\mathsf E(\abs{X_k-X_{k-1}}\mid X_{k-1}))\\[1ex] &=~ \frac{1}{N(N-1)}\left(\sum_{x=2}^N \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} (x-y)+\sum_{x=1}^{N-1} \sum_{y=x+1}^N(y-x)\right) \\[1ex] &~~\vdots\end{align}$$

Use a similar procedure to evaluate the standard deviation.

Comment: you can not fix this by; first find the permutation for all elements then calculate the total value and from that get the mean?  but this willl not work on N 20 as calculating the permutation will be impossible